# How can I add bleed to a PDF book cover using Photoshop?

Tags: pdf, adobe, photoshop, adobe-indesign, export-to-pdf

I have a book cover sent as a PDF which is according 5x8 dimensions, only that is does not have bleed and I need to add it. I am using Adobe InDesign CC 2015 and Adobe Photoshop CC 2015. How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Create a document in indesign and place the pdf into the document, centered. The document must have bigger dimensions for the bleed. Then put whatever in the bleed that's necessary.

A better way would be to load the pdf file into Illustrator and add the bleed there. Color matching will be a lot more accurate that way. Especially if the pdf contains any vector artwork like outlined fonts. Make sure you've got the correct fonts installed.

If the pdf only contains bitmap images, you could import it into photoshop. Make sure you've created a new document with the needed dimensions and resolution. 300 to 600 dpi would be a good starting point. Usually type will not look clean and sharp when using photoshop since its working on a picture (bitmap). Illustrator or Indesign would make type much cleaner.

If it's possible to get the source files instead, that would be the preferred method. Even if you'd have to redo the artwork would be better to have the original source files/pictures/fonts etc.